# Exit the main sub if a called sub calls `Exit Sub`

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that calls another sub and most often I need to exit the called sub and stop executing the rest of the sub that called it.

So I have the sub `Add_Format_Button_Click` that calls another sub:

```
call CheckEmptyComboboxValues
```

And most often `CheckEmptyComboboxValues` will end up on

```
Exit sub
```

But the `Add_Format_Button_Click` will continue executing the rest of it. This is where I need help because when `CheckEmptyComboboxValues` exits, I need the `Add_Format_Button_Click`  to also exit.

Could someone help me solve this, seemingly simple problem?

EDIT: `CheckEmptyComboboxValues` contains tens if not hundreds of if statements that follow the structure of:

```
If Format_Layout.FilmType.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Specify a film type!", , ("Film Type"): Exit sub
End If
```

So I guess I need to turn that `exit sub` value into something I can check in the main sub with an if statement like

```
if CheckEmptyComboboxValues .value = "Exit sub" Then
exit sub
```

Comment: Or set a boolean global which is updated within CheckEmptyCombo... and then has its value tested in Add_Format_Click after the call

Comment: Ok, what would be the code for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 solutions, each of them works for your case. I would go with the first or last solution. Depends a bit on the design of the rest of your project:

#### 1. Function

```
Function CheckEmptyComboboxValues() As Boolean
    If AnythingOddHappens Then
        Exit Function 
    End If

    CheckEmptyComboboxValues = True
End Function
```

The result of this function is only `True` if it runs through the end, whenever you exit it before it is `False`

```
Sub Example()
    If Not CheckEmptyComboboxValues Then Exit Sub

    'instead of 
    'Call CheckEmptyComboboxValues 
End Sub
```

#### 2. Procedure with cancel

```
Sub CheckEmptyComboboxValues(ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    If AnythingOddHappens Then
        Cancel = True
        Exit Sub 
    End If

End Sub 


Sub Example()
    Dim Cancel As Boolean
    Call CheckEmptyComboboxValues(Cancel)  

    If Cancel Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

This can be used, but here I see no advantage and would prefer the function above. This method can be useful if you already have a function with a return value and want an additional cancel or in case you write code for an event.

#### 3. Throw an error

```
Sub CheckEmptyComboboxValues()
    If AnythingOddHappens Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "CheckEmptyComboboxValues", "Something odd happened"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub 

Sub Example()
    On Error Goto ERR_HANDLER
    Call CheckEmptyComboboxValues  

    Exit Sub
ERR_HANDLER:
    MsgBox "check failed"
End Sub
```

This can be an advantage if you have multiple check procedures/functions that can throw errors. Compared with the first or second solution where you need to check the result of each single check procedure/function this solution needs only one error handler, and threfore comes with slim code.

This also has the advantage that the check procedure now can return different type of errors that your calling sub can use to provide further assistance to the user. While the first 2 solutions are more like *"It didn't pass the check"* the last solution can provide more detailed information like *"It didn't pass the check because of A/B/C happened"* depending on which error was raised.

```
Sub CheckEmptyComboboxValues()
    If AnythingOddHappens Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 513, "CheckEmptyComboboxValues", "Something odd happened"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' more code here …
    If AnythingDifferentOddHappens Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 514, "CheckEmptyComboboxValues", "Something different odd happened"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you can use the different error numbers to provide a more detailde infomation to the user about **what** went wrong and not just *something* went wrong.

```
Sub Example()
    On Error Goto ERR_HANDLER
    Call CheckEmptyComboboxValues  

    Exit Sub
ERR_HANDLER:  'possibility to give a more detailed information
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case vbObjectError + 513
        MsgBox "check A failed"
    Case vbObjectError + 514
        MsgBox "check B failed"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Undefined fail"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: And how do I call a function from that main sub? Because
    Call CheckEmptyComboboxValues returns a compile error: invalid qualifier.

And is the main sub if statement:

    If CheckEmptyComboboxValues.Value = False Then
    Exit Sub

Comment: @Eduards Please read carefully again it is all in my answer. The function is called like `If Not CheckEmptyComboboxValues Then Exit Sub`. This runs the function and checks its result. If it is `False` then it exits.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite `CheckEmptyComboboxValues` to a function which returns a `boolean`. In `Add_Format_Button_Click` you can then write

```
if CheckEmptyComboboxValues then
   ' You could give a message
   Exit Sub 
else
   ' rest of the code of 
   ' Add_Format_Button_Click
end if
```

`CheckEmptyComboboxValues` might look like that

```
Function CheckEmptyComboboxValues  as boolean

' code goes here
if .... then
    CheckEmptyComboboxValues   = False
    exit function
else 

   ' other code
end if

CheckEmptyComboboxValues   = True

End Function
```

**Update** based on the edit

```
Function CheckEmptyComboboxValues() As Boolean
    
    ' ....

    If Format_Layout.FilmType.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Specify a film type!", , ("Film Type")
        CheckEmptyComboboxValues = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ' ....
    
    CheckEmptyComboboxValues = False


End Function
```

Comment: Not really. I literally need what I asked and described. No work arounds or nothing because I could also copy paste that whole checking sub for each occasion I need resulting in unnecessary thousands lines of code repeated for each button click I have. There's a reason why all the checking code is in a sub. And in case something was wrong that checking sub returns a message and exits sub. In that case I need to also stop, exit or end sub taht called the checking

Comment: So, you do not want to re-write `CheckEmptyComboboxValues` to a function  and you also  do not want to re-write the other code as well. Then it will become very difficult to help you. What is the reason why all the checking code is in a sub which cannot be rewritten to a fucntion which is more than easy.

Comment: Because it's hundreds of lines. It's a checking system if everything is correct so far before user moves on. I call that sub for EVERY action that user performs. I mean every button click etc.

I am sure that if there's function like exit sub that exits current sub, that there must be a function that stops executing the sub that called checking sub, like end (enter sub name) or something.

Comment: I am not aware of a  function for  _I am sure that if there's function like exit sub that exits current sub_  for that unless you want to use `End`. But this will end the execution of the code completely. But it sounds like you need a control array as you seem to have similar code for every button.

Comment: End doesn't work because exiting that checking sub is a result of an if function:

    If Format_Layout.Language.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Specify a blueprint language!", , ("Language"): End Sub
    End If

And there's tens of such if statements in checking sub.

Comment: I cannot recommend ever to use `End`! Storax is right what you ask for does not exist in VBA. Go the way Storax showed. Another solution can be to raise an error in your checking sub that you catch in the calling sub. Anyway there is no way without changing the code in both subs.

Comment: @PEH: Yes, I totally agree. Using `End` is not a good idea at all. As I said this will end the code completely and that is usually not a good idea. But that would probably be the only possibilty in case the TO does not want to re-write his code in the way  I suggested. But in the case the TO uses `End` he hase to bear the consequences.

Comment: I am not against adding code, friend. I suppose I need to convert that if result "exit sub" to a value that in main sub I can check if called sub returned this value

Comment: Instead of a function you can also pass a boolean parameter to your sub which you check. But I would prefer a function in this case.

Comment: Alright, but how do I do that. Your code in the answer is confusing.

The CheckEmptyComboboxValues has only If statements that follow teh exact structure as example: 

    If Format_Layout.Language.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Specify a blueprint language!", , ("Language"): End Sub
End If

Comment: Please edit you post accordingly to show what code you have in `CheckEmptyComboboxValues`. That will make it easier to help you.

Comment: If I have understood the requirement based on the name `CheckEmptyComboboxValues` then you do not need a sub but a function So `Function CheckEmptyComboboxValues() As Boolean` as @Storax suggested. Not sure why do you not want to use that. BTW it is not a "Workaround" It is the rght way to handle your requirement. This fuction then can be used at other places as well if required.

Comment: Edited the main post :)